# How format my output from my ostringstream using setw?

Tags: c++, format, out

I been trying to format my output from my program using setw method but is not working? This is my output, big gaps between countires (ex: United States):

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
string itemToString(const Country& i) {
  ostringstream out;
  out.setf(ios::fixed);
  out.setf(ios::showpoint);
  out.precision(2);
  out << i.name
      << setw(20) << "|" << i.population
      << setw(10) << "|" << i.areaSQ
      << setw(10) << "|" << i.popDensitySQ
      << setw(10) << "|" << i.netMigration
      << setw(10) << "|" << i.GDP
      << setw(10) << "|" << i.literacy  
      << setw(10) << "|" << i.birthRate << "\n";
  return out.str();
}
```

I want to see if there is anything that I can do to fix those big gaps between countries like United States.

Comment: You want to use `setw` ***before*** the field that should be padded to the given width, and not after.